# How to keep track of users who are not logged in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am writing a simple e-commerce web app with Django.

I want **Anonymous Users** (unregistered guests) to still be able to add items to their cart and proceed to checkout without having to register or log in. I am having trouble figuring out how to actually keep track of them (*according to best practices/with security in mind*), if these types of users don't have an identifiable username/id that Django provides.

Concretely, suppose I have these models:

```
class Shirt(models.Model):
    """Represents the type of item I am selling."""
    ...

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    """Represents an individual entry in an Order."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Shirt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=1)

class Order(models.Model):
    """Represents an order, i.e. a 'collection' of entries."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
```

When I work with logged in users, my models' fields get populated with corresponding user objects (that logic is already implemented with the help of **request.user**). Of course, that doesn't work with unregistered people.

I have already read some info on django sessions and cookies, but I am not quite sure I get how to make it all work in a nice and clean way.

I am just starting out with web development (and Django, by extension), so I would greatly appreciate some advice!

Comment: IMHO sessions and cookies are the way to go. What you choose is dependent, on how long you want the user to be remembered,

Comment: @ger.s.brett Thanks for your input! For this project, it's not really crucial – it needs to "just work" for now. If I were to use sessions, would it be a good idea to add something like 'session_key' field to my custom User model and use that whenever I want to, say, create a new order or add an item to their cart? Or is there a better implementation?

Comment: This works automatically, just have a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#examples